# read file Operation not permitted even for root

Tags: linux, file, permissions, filesystems, file-permissions

I downloaded a [OctoPi](http://docstech.net/OctoPiMirror/2014-09-09-wheezy-octopi-0.10.0.zip) and unziped the file in my local filesystem (EXT4):

```
$ unzip 2014-09-09-wheezy-octopi-0.10.0.zip
```

Just one file was unzipped:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user  user  3276800000 Oct 27 14:46 2014-09-09-wheezy-octopi-0.10.0.img
```

now I want to use image for SD card, but even **cat** file writes error (now as root, i tried that with user before):

```
# cat 2014-09-09-wheezy-octopi-0.10.0.img 
cat: 2014-09-09-wheezy-octopi-0.10.0.img: Operation not permitted
```

I tried unzipping it to another location (different fs, USB stick) but it has the same behaviour.
also I tried the strace:

```
# strace cat 2014-09-09-wheezy-octopi-0.10.0.img 
execve("/bin/cat", ["cat", "2014-09-09-wheezy-octopi-0.10.0."...], [/* 27 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x718000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1fb2a65000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=166255, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 166255, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f1fb2a3c000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\37\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1844160, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3949184, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f1fb2480000
mprotect(0x7f1fb263a000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f1fb283a000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1ba000) = 0x7f1fb283a000
mmap(0x7f1fb2840000, 17024, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1fb2840000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1fb2a3b000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1fb2a39000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f1fb2a39740) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1fb283a000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x60b000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f1fb2a67000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f1fb2a3c000, 166255)          = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x718000
brk(0x739000)                           = 0x739000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3165552, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3165552, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f1fb217b000
close(3)                                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(136, 1), ...}) = 0
open("2014-09-09-wheezy-octopi-0.10.0.img", O_RDONLY) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
write(2, "cat: ", 5cat: )                    = 5
write(2, "2014-09-09-wheezy-octopi-0.10.0."..., 352014-09-09-wheezy-octopi-0.10.0.img) = 35
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2570, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1fb2a64000
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2570
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f1fb2a64000, 4096)            = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpacsudo k/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, ": Operation not permitted", 25: Operation not permitted) = 25
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

On different system (checked just one) I was able to read it.

I have Kubuntu 14.10 x64 with latest updates.
Linux mycomp 3.16.0-28-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 12 17:37:40 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Actually I write the image via pipes (it works):

```
unzip -p ... | pv | dd ...
```

but I want to know, **why the file is not readable and where I do mistake**.

....

Later I have the same experience with rapsbian:

```
wget -O 2014-12-24-wheezy-raspbian.zip http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_latest
```

Answer (score 0):

rename

```
mv 2014-09-09-wheezy-octopi-0.10.0.img initrd.gz
```

and then do unzip

Comment: Ok, I tried it:
I renamed the zip, also the img file
tried to gunzip it.
Nothing helped.

Comment: can you move it to a different location using cp and then try this method?

Comment: the img: i cannot cp it because it is not readable;

the zip: I can cp it (different FS on the same system), I unzipped it (via gunzip) and still the same behavior.;

I tried different system an it works ...